# Wrong answer in Codechef MasterChef

Tags: set, knapsack-problem

I am facing issues in the solution for the problem http://www.codechef.com/problems/MCHEF , here is my solution http://ideone.com/SsbABr
I have solved the problem using knapsack and set but i am getting wrong answer, can't seem to figure out why! I have also seen the editorial for the same which also does the same. I believe that my DP code for knapsack is correct.
Problem seems to be in the below segment which uses set to insert and maintain interval costs, so that i can get the minimum cost for each element.

    `vector<int> L[n],R[n];
    vector<oper> operarray;
    vector<int> cost;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        int j,k,val;
        cin >> j >> k >> val;
        L[j-1].push_back(i);
        R[k-1].push_back(i);
        cost.push_back(val);
    }
    set<pair<int,int> > iset;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<L[i].size();j++){
            int index = L[i][j];
            iset.insert(make_pair(cost[index],index));
        }
        b[i] = iset.begin()->first;
        for(int j=0;j<R[i].size();j++){
        int index = R[i][j];
        iset.erase(make_pair(cost[index],index));
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the issue was that i was not checking if the set was empty and compiler didn't prompt any run time error when i was assigning the begin element of the empty set to array element in the line

```
b[i] = iset.begin()->first;
```

The above should be changed to

```
if(!iset.empty())
    b[i] = iset.begin()->first;
```